# Under which of the four fundamental forces does suction force come?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, pressure

Suction force doesn't come under strong nuclear force,weak nuclear force or gravitational force. So does it come under electromagnetic force?

If so then why,like how do charges play a role in the development of high pressure and low pressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "suction force" is really a misnomer because there is no pulling force involved rather it is all to do with "pushing" forces (aka pressure).

In this context the pressure exerted by the air is due to collisions between air molecules and the "sucker".
That being so it is the interactions between the electron shells of the atoms involved which produce the forces which cause momentum changes.
The interactions between electrons is electromagnetic in origin.

Answer (score 3):

All so-called “contact forces” are electromagnetic in origin. At the atomic level, the outer electron shells of the atoms in object A repel those of object B, which causes objects A and B to push against each other.

Comment: Is "suction" truly a "contact force"? I don't know. Just not sure. Since suction is the result of a pressure differential causing a fluid to accelerate (e.g, liquid accelerating up a straw). What are your thoughts?

Comment: Yes, suction results from pressure differences. Pressure arises from contact forces (object A pushing against object B).